# Halachic ground for opening an voluntary war against other nations

Tags: halacha-theory, army-military-war

Jews are Halachicly allowed to start a *voluntary* war to conquer and enslave other nations and to expand the Jewish kingdom (Rambam Melachim 5).

As the Halachah forbids both killing and robbing non-Jews "in private", by single Jews, what Halachic ground is there for allowing to open a war that results in the expropriation of property and very probable mass killing?

Comment: I think the Brisker Rav ah"t in Parshas Bo/Beshalach discusses this.. Will try look it up and post answer.

Comment: IIRC, 'acts of war' are not considered 'murder'.

Comment: @chortkov2 Good point! I understand when murder is part of an obligatory war but in voluntary?

Comment: The way I understand it - once in a state of war, there parameters change... I need to have a look at it

Comment: Not to mention that certain nations/tribes need to be and WILL get killed Berzat HaShem (in due time, may it come speedily as this will be the precursor of Mashiachs arival if I asume it correctly). In the light of the Ultimate Redemption, it will all come with acceptance and a smile.